# Navigate to sql position

Tags: sql, intellij-idea

IntelliJ pro comes with an embedded SQL editor.

Sometimes, I type a wrong request and the database returns an error and the corresponding SQL position.

Example :

> [2017-01-02 16:32:35] [42P01] ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "customer"
>     **Position : 516**

**Problem** : for readability reasons, the request is written on multiple lines, making it harder to find the position 516.

Up to now, the only solution I got is to delete the `\n` characters in order to have the request on only one line then navigate to the 516th column.

But I guess there is a better way, like a fancy keyboard shortcut?

Comment: Did you checked my answer?

Comment: @TomePejoski Yes. Unfortunately, if I understand it correctly, it does not answer the question. The error message returned by the database tells at which character is the error, regardless of the number of lines. It only says that the error is at character 516 (so it might be at line 42 and column 53 for example).

Answer (score 7):

It's been a while you asked but I'll answer anyway to help others:

- Download "Character Position" plug-in from here:

  https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10334-character-position
- Install plugin & Restart IntelliJ

Character position will be shown in the bottom-left corner of the editor.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

In my case I press F2 and cursor go there.

Comment: This doesn't give enough context to be helpful. Without context, a reader will ask: what problem does this answer solve?

Answer (score -3):

The current caret position (line number and offset) is displayed in the [Status Bar](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/status-bar.html). You can *click it* to open the **Go To Line** dialog box.

[image]

Change the second number to the needed position of your character and will be navigated directly.